# Perl: how can I put all my inline C code into a separate file?

Tags: c, perl, inline

This problem is so simple I can feel the RTFM's coming.  However, I've been looking at the docs ([Inline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline), [Inline-C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C), [Inline-C-Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C-Cookbook) ) all morning and I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

I want to use inline C, but I don't want to have C code in the same file as my perl code.

(Emacs doesn't like having two languages in one file.  In principle this is a matter of convenience, but in practice I'm having to edit my C in one file then copy-paste it into my perl script.)

Here is working perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Inline C => DATA;
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(sum);
use feature qw(say);

my @array = (1..10);
say "native perl: ", sum(@array), ", Inline C: ", sum1(\@array);

__END__
__C__

double sum1(AV* array) {
  int i;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (i=0; i<=av_len(array); i++) {
    SV** elem = av_fetch(array, i, 0);
    if (elem != NULL)
      sum += SvNV(*elem);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

(thanks to [mobrule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503763/how-can-i-pass-an-array-to-a-c-function-in-perl-xs) for getting me this far.)

I want to move all of the C code (or as much as possible) into a separate header file.

What I can do is put `sum1` into a header, and do this:

```
# same perl as above except now say sum2 instead of sum1
__END__
__C__
#include "sum.h"

double sum2(AV* array) {
    sum1(array);
}
```

This is good enough as I no longer have to edit the C in perl-mode, but I wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: @Pedro Silva eye of the beholder and all that.  just seems a bit redundant to me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can put your C code in a separate file and use `Inline::bind` to load it at runtime

```
use Inline;
use File::Slurp;

my $data = read_file('source.c');
Inline->bind(C => $data);
```

or loading the source code in a `BEGIN {}` block to bind it at compile time

```
my $data;
use File::Slurp;
BEGIN {
    $data = read_file('source.c');
}
use Inline C => $data;
```

Comment: thanks!  I was surprised to find that this solution doesn't recompile at each execution.  Inline is smart!

Comment: If 'source.c' includes 'source2.h' which is defined in 'source2.c', do you know how to do it so both are compiled and linked?

Answer (score 4):

At least with recent versions of Inline, you can simply specify a file name instead of a string when use-ing Inline:

```
use Inline C => "./test.c";
```

The caveat here is that Inline::C uses a simple regexp approach to determining whether its argument "looks like" a filename, which is why the "./" part is important. It's also a good idea to start your C file with a `#line 1 test.c` directive, so the C debugger will know about it.