# Perl Inline::Python module, how to put code into a string

Tags: python, perl, inline, cpan

I am learning perl Inline::Python library. In the example of cpan website, we have

```
   print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
   print "9 - 16 = ", subtract(9, 16), "\n";

   use Inline Python => <<'END_OF_PYTHON_CODE';
   def add(x,y): 
      return x + y

   def subtract(x,y):
      return x - y

   END_OF_PYTHON_CODE
```

Is it possible to put python code into string so that I can create the python code in the runtime? For example, something like:

```
my $python_code = "
def add(x,y):
   return x + y
";
print $python_code;
use Inline Python => "$python_code";
print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
```

We have a projects that will dynamically create python functions at the runtime. And we want to call these functions. Is py_eval() the way to go? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you embedding a Python interpreter?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Our perl program needs to run python functions that are created at the runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No experience with `Inline::Python`, but with `Inline::C` [you can use the `bind` function to set code at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188349/), so maybe this will work:

```
my $python_code = "
def add(x,y):
   return x + y
";
print $python_code;
Inline->bind( Python => $python_code );
print "9 + 16 = ", add(9, 16), "\n";
```