# Does perl Inline::C support multiple dependent C files?

Tags: c, perl, inline, xs

This question is based on: [Perl: how can I put all my inline C code into a separate file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188349/perl-how-can-i-put-all-my-inline-c-code-into-a-separate-file), but for multiple files.

Suppose you want to include C file in perl named `foo.c`:

```
#include "bar.h"

int foo(...
```

As you can see, `foo.c` depends on `bar.h` which is associated to `bar.c`.

Is there a way Inline::C can compile both `foo.c` and `bar.c` and link `bar.o` so `foo()` works properly?

Answer (score 1):

Inline::C generates a `.xs` file in a previously non-existent directory from the provided code. It then uses the standard Perl tool chain to create a shared library from it. At no point is there any `foo.c` or `bar.c` for the tool chain to compile.

What you could do is create a library (static or shared) from the two compilation units you describe (`foo.c` and `bar.c`). Inline::C can easily link to these. [Alien](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien) provides infrastructure for creating libraries for modules to use. [This page](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Alien-Build/lib/Alien/Build/Manual/AlienAuthor.pod) documents how to create an Alien::* module which builds your library.